# How to changing css on bootstrap button Group

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

The below code toggles a button in a group. I'm having fun tying to change the CSS of these buttons, in particular the selected button.

```
<span class="label label-primary">Age</span>
    <div class="btn-group" id="ageID">
    <button type="button" style="width:120px" class="btnMyAge btn-default" id="3">Under 10</button>
    <button type="button" style="width:120px" class="btnMyAge btn-default" id="1">Under 50</button>
    <button type="button" style="width:120px" class="btnMyAge btn-default" id="2">Over 50</button>
</div>
<script>
    $(".btn-group > .btnMyAge").click(function () {                                 
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    })
</script>
```

My custom CSS file:

```
.btnMyAge, .btn:active
{
    background-color: #ffe13a;
}
```

Comment: I guess it should be **`css`**

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: Also `id=ageID` should be in quotes like `id="ageID"`

Comment: Your code works for me. Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k4b2ywoa/

Comment: yes that works for the bold statement, but this  background-color: #ffe13a; does not on my system, it does on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your CSS to

```
.active {
    background-color: #ffe13a;
}
```

or else the `background-color` is applied to all buttons because of the `btnMyAge` class.

Answer (score 0):

The background color is not changed but the bold statement does.
If I remove the first line below from my _Layout.cshtml the background works??

```
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/custom.css">
```